# Run integration tests in a specific directory with gradle command

Tags: java, gradle, junit, junit4

I have gradle project with below structure

ParentDirectory

> component1

> component2

> testsuites

> unittest

When I run command ./gradlew test
It ran all tests under unittest not integration tests

I have some integration tests like aTest, bTest etc in testsuites directory, when I run below command it does something like (Configure project...) but I guess its not running integration junit tests as it doesn't show test details

```
./gradlew clean test --tests com.x.y.aTest
```

Here com.x.y is package location to aTest, what is seen on import in aTest class.

Please let me know how can I run single integration test class & multiple integration tests with gradle command in terminal?

Comment: What about ./gradlew integrationTest --tests com.x.y.aTest, or use whatever is your integration test task name? Looks like those aren't captured under the default "test" task